# -bash: alias: /path/to/folder: not found

Tags: terminal, bash

Mac OS Sierra, 10.12.3

I inserted this line into my `.bash_profile`:

```
alias myfolder="cd ~/path/to/folder"
```

But when I type this into Terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: alias: Users/myuser/path/to/folder: not found
```

Basically, I want to be able to type "myfolder" from anywhere in the directory structure and have it change to that alias path. But I haven't been able to get it to work.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I was already using the `cd` command. Edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Well, the error means that `path/to/folder` doesn't exist. Can you post the contents of your home directory? (do `cd ~; ls -la`)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing bash alias, macOS alias and (soft-)link.

The bash alias requires some executable to be called but a path to a folder is no executable.

So use `alias myfolder='cd ~/path/to/folder'` in your .bash_profile to change to the desired directory. `~/path/to/folder` has to be a valid path of course - or it won't work.

Comment: Folders in Unix _are_ executable ( do an `ls -la` in a directory and you'll find the `x` permission set). If you type in the name of a folder, you will be changed to that directory. If the directory exists, the alias will work.

Comment: @KisaAyano No, a folder isn't executable - it's searchable!

Comment: EDIT: They are in zsh, not bash. I've been in zsh-land too long and forgot that zsh's typing in folder name aliases to a directory change is a new feature :)

Comment: @KisaAyano ;-) !

Comment: Sorry, I was already using `cd` in the alias command. I also verified that the path exists. I can actually do `cd ~/path/to/folder` inside Terminal and it correctly switches to that path. It's just that the alias command doesn't work.

Comment: @EgeErsoz use `'` instead of `"` like in my answer!

Comment: I tried that. Same error. :(